# Install Ubuntu Patch to solve CVE

Tags: ghostscript

Can someone please help me on how to install the following patch to solve a CVE?
[https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ghostscript/9.22~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ghostscript/9.22%7Edfsg+1-0ubuntu1)

Comment: This patch has been merged years ago.

Comment: Show the output of `apt-cache policy ghostscript`

Answer (score 3):

The patch you've indicated is **already merged** into the Ubuntu packaging and has been present since at least 18.04 in the repositories.  In 18.04, there's also the newer security release version of `9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.18.04.13` as well which has *more* patches and fixes for issues already merged in it. (available in the -updates and -security repositories for 18.04, and -security is usually enabled by default).

Ubuntu 20.04 and later already have a much newer version of Ghostscript which is already at and beyond the patch level you've indicated.  There is **no action** needed on your part unless you are using a version of Ubuntu older than 18.04 (in which case, time to update your system to a newer Ubuntu)

Check the version of the package you're using with `apt-cache policy ghostscript` - if the 'Installed' value is a version at or later than `9.22~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1` or `9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.18.04.13` (for 18.04) systems then you're already good.  If you're on Ubuntu 20.04 or newer, you don't even have to check as it's already part of the packaging.